# How to check whether a string contains lowercase letter, uppercase letter, special character and digit?

Tags: java, regex

I've been Googling a lot and I didn't find an answer for my question:

How can I check with a regular expression whether a string contains at least one of each of these:

- Uppercase letter
- Lowercase letter
- Digit
- Special Character: `` ~`!@#$%^&*()-_=+\|[{]};:'",<.>/? ``

So I need at least a capital letter *and* at least a small letter *and* at least a digit *and* at least a special character.

I'm sure the answer is very simple, but I can't find it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Google for "regex for strong password validation"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This does what you want in java as a single regex, although I would personally use something like the solution provided by Mark Rhodes.  This will get ridiculous quick (if it isn't already...) as the rules get more complicated.

```
String regex = "^(?=.*?\\p{Lu})(?=.*?[\\p{L}&&[^\\p{Lu}]])(?=.*?\\d)" + 
               "(?=.*?[`~!@#$%^&*()\\-_=+\\\\\\|\\[{\\]};:'\",<.>/?]).*$"
```

1. ^ This matches the beginning of the string.  It's not strictly necessary for this to work, but I find it helps readability and understanding.  Also, using it when you can often makes a big performance improvement and is almost never a penalty.
2. (?=*X*)  This is called a positive lookahead.  Basically what we're saying is "The beginning of the string (^) must be followed by this thing *X* in order for a match, but **DO NOT** advance the cursor to the end of *X*, stay at the beginning of the line.  (that's the "look ahead" part.)
3. .*?\p{Lu}  eat characters after the beginning of the line until you find a capital letter.  This will fail to match if no capital letter is found.  We use \p{Lu} instead of A-Z because we don't want people from other parts of the world to throw up their hands and complain about how our software was written by an ignorant American.
4. Now we go back to the beginning of the line (we go back because we used lookahead) and start a search for .*?[\p{L}&&[^\p{Lu}]] shorthand for "all letters, minus the capitals" (hence matches lower case).
5. .*?\d + .*?[`~!@#$%^&*()\-_=+\\\|\[{\]};:'\",<.>/?] repeat for digits and for your list of special characters.
6. .*$ Match everything else until the end of the line.  We do this just because of the semantics of the 'matches' methods in java that see if the *entire* string is a match for the regex.  You could leave this part of and use the Matcher#find() method and get the same result.
7. [The Owl is one of the best books ever written on any technical subject.](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do)  And it's short and fast to read.  I cannot recommend it enough.

Comment: +1 Thank you, Affe, can you explain this to me? I must confess that I'm not a regular expression expert and I just wanted to solve my problem with regular expressions, instead of checking my strings character-by-character.

Comment: Thank you Affe, I would like to upvote you again, but I can't. Ok, I can upvote your comment.

Answer (score 44):

Regular expressions aren't very good for tests where you require *all* of several conditions to be met.

The simplest answer therefore is not to try and test them all at the same time, but just to try each of the four classes in turn.

Your code might be *fractionally* slower, but it'll be easier to read and maintain, e.g.

```
public boolean isLegalPassword(String pass) {

     if (!pass.matches(".*[A-Z].*")) return false;

     if (!pass.matches(".*[a-z].*")) return false;

     if (!pass.matches(".*\\d.*")) return false;

     if (!pass.matches(".*[~!.......].*")) return false;

     return true;
}
```

**EDIT** fixed quote marks - been doing too much damned JS programming...

Comment: @AlanMoore I gave you a +1 by error... It is true that `.matches()` is woefully misnamed regex-wise and expects to match the whole input, however the solution is _not_ to use `.*` around. The real solution is to use `.find()` instead, which performs real regex matching.

Comment: @fge: Unfortunately, String doesn't have a `find()` method, and I don't see any point in telling people to use `Pattern.compile("[A-Z]").matcher(pass).find())` when `pass.matches(".*[A-Z].*")` gets the job done.  The only thing to watch out for is if there are line separator characters (`\n`, `\r`, etc.) in the string, and I don't think that's an issue here.

Comment: This will also allow you to return condition-specific error messages to your user, if you so choose.

Answer (score 16):

I agree that @Alnitak's answer is the easiest to read, however it suffers from the fact that it has to evaluate the regexs each time it's run.  Since the regexs are fixed, it makes sense to compile them then compare against them.
e.g. Something like:

```
    private static final Pattern [] passwordRegexes = new Pattern[4];
    {
        passwordRegexes[0] = Pattern.compile(".*[A-Z].*");
        passwordRegexes[1] = Pattern.compile(".*[a-z].*");
        passwordRegexes[2] = Pattern.compile(".*\\d.*");
        passwordRegexes[3] = Pattern.compile(".*[~!].*");
    }
    public boolean isLegalPassword(String pass) {

        for(int i = 0; i < passwordRegexes.length; i++){
            if(!passwordRegexes[i].matcher(pass).matches())
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

When run 100,000 times on a 10 character password the above code was twice as fast.  Although, I guess now you could say this code is harder to read!  Never mind!

Comment: +1. It all depends on your requirements, doesn't it. Hardware limitations always factor in, and anybody who fails to consider them in their design will eventually pay the cost, whether it's as obvious as a three-day run time for a single SQL query taking your application down, or as subtle as having to buy a larger fractional colo three months sooner than you might have otherwise.

Answer (score 7):

Because these will not appear in any particular order, you will need lookahead assertions for each required character class:

```
(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[~!@#$%\^&*()\-_=+\|\[{\]};:'",<.>/?])
```

(NOTE: because backslash, caret, hyphen, and square brackets can be special inside a range, they should be backslash escaped if they appear in the range, as shown in the fourth lookahead assertion.)

This construct can be made considerably more readable using whitespace and comments, if your regex variant supports the `x` modifier. In `java.util.regex`, you can do:

```
(?x)         # extended syntax
(?=.*[A-Z])  # look ahead for at least one upper case
(?=.*[a-z])  # look ahead for at least one lower case
(?=.*[0-9])  # look ahead for at least one numeral
(?=.*[~!@#$%\^&*()\-_=+\|\[{\]};:'",<.>/?])
             # look ahead for at least one of the listed symbols
```

Comment: and this proves my point - I've been using regexps for god knows how many years, and have never used a lookahead assertion, and would struggle to read this.  The version with four simple regexps can be read by anyone.

Comment: (+1) Good answer.  Just make sure to use global matching (which is the most common anyway).

Comment: @Alnitak I have now illustrated the use of extended syntax, which makes the expression easy to read and is supported by the OP's language. I tend to avoid it in examples just to make my expressions more generally useful even with regex implementations that do not have extended syntax.

Comment: Tim's right.  Also, how are you applying the regex?  If you use the `matches()` method, you need to finish the regex off with `.*` or something, to make it consume the whole string.

Comment: The original question does not supply context. It does not say, for example, that the regex will be handed "as is" to `matches()`. The OP may well want to use the solution with `matcher()`, or as part of a larger regular expression. So I am simply providing the fragment that will perform the necessary assertion. If the desired answer is made more concrete, I can modify the code to fit the specific need.

Comment: +1, this is very interesting, I will study your answer. Thank you very much for the insight

Comment: @Alnitak I take your point that regexes can be write-only, but that is not the issue here. Doesn't your case basically boil down to "I've never used a lookahead assertion"?

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

- Big letter: [A-Z]
- Small letter: [a-z]
- Digit: [0-9] or \d
- Special character: [^A-Za-z0-9]  (That is, not any of the others, where `^` negates the class)

---

If you want to test for 'this' or 'that', you can combine those ranges.  For example, Big or Small letters would be `[A-Za-z]`.

Comment: The OP is looking not for 'this' *or* 'that', but for 'this' *and* 'that'. I cannot think of a way to do this with character classes alone.

Comment: +1@MetaEd Yes, MetaEd, I'm looking for at least a big letter and at least a small letter and at least a digit and at least a special character.

Comment: It's not a complete answer, but at the least the link is relevant, which is why I haven't deleted it.

Answer (score -1):

`\w`: is used for matching alpha-numeric (alphabets can be either big or small) 
`\W`: is used for matching special characters

I think this RegEx will be helpful for you:

```
[\w|\W]+
```

Here's a good [RegEx Simulator](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/), you can use it for building your own RegEx.

Comment: -1. "`\W` matches special characters" is misleading at best.  `\W` is the complement of `\w`, so `[\w\W]` matches any word character, or any character that's *not* a word character--i.e, any character.  (There's no need to specify "OR" in a character class, so `|` matches a literal `|`--and that's already being matched by `\W`.) Anyway, you missed the point of the question, which was to ensure that **one of each** of the four kinds of character is present.

Comment: +1@Alan Moore Yes, MetaEd, I'm looking for at least a big letter and at least a small letter and at least a digit and at least a special character. I'll edit my post to contain "one of each" insteat of "one of all these" to avoid confusions